# Open Dialer AND Open web links in webview[Error] ANDROID

Tags: android, webview

```
package com.example.t2noob;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity extends Activity
{   
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:")) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                    Uri.parse(url)); 
            startActivity(intent); 
    }else if(url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
    }



  WebView mWebView;




  public void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
  {



      super.onCreate(paramBundle);
      requestWindowFeature(1);
      getWindow().setFlags(1024, 1024);
      setContentView(2130903040);
      final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Home);//BUTTONS ON TOP OF WEBVIEW. HOME
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("test.com");
          }
      });
      final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Back);//BUTTONS ON TOP OF WEBVIEW. BACK
      button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            mWebView.goBack();
          }
          });

      this.mWebView = ((WebView)findViewById(2131034112));
      this.mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      this.mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
      this.mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      this.mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
      this.mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
      this.mWebView.loadUrl("test.com");
      this.mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

       }


      public boolean onKeyDown(int paramInt, KeyEvent paramKeyEvent)//LETS USER PUSH BACK BUTTON ON PHONE TO GO BACK A PAGE IN WEBVIEW.
      {
        boolean bool;
        if ((paramInt != 4) || (!this.mWebView.canGoBack()))
        {
     bool = super.onKeyDown(paramInt, paramKeyEvent);
 }
 else
 {
   this.mWebView.goBack();
   bool = true;
 }
 return bool;
}   

}
```

So i have the above source code the function shoudOverrideUrlLoading
should catch both the web links to open them in the webview if I didn't misread
and open phone numbers with the android dialer.
with the above code i can get links to open in the webview but it wont open the numbers in the dialer.
If i add this code to the program.

```
private static final WebViewClient Webview = null;
this.mWebView.setWebViewClient(Webview);
```

I can get the dialer to open but then the web links wont open in the webview but will actually open in the default browser.
So i would like some help in how to get it to open phone numbers in the dialer and web links in the webview and not just have either or.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  if(url.contains("tel:"))
  {
   //make the substring with the telephone number, and invoke intent for dialer
  }
 else
   view.loadUrl(url);
   return true;
}
```

}

And set the web view client as

```
this.mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

This will make sure the links are opened in the same web view, and not the browser.
Note : Remove all other uses of setWebViewClient()

Edited : This will solve!

Comment: Yea I know that this should fix the links opening in the webview but I want the web links to open in the webview and the telephone numbers, sms to open the dialer and messaging app respectively. with your code it will just open the links in the webview but wont open the dialer when a number is clicked.(i actually had your code before but when i added the stuff to open the dialer when a number was clicked it wont open the web links in the webview.) so i wanted to know if i was doing something wrong. Becauseit isn'tcatching both the phone numbers and the weblinks. it just does one or the other.

Comment: Use something like this, if(url.contains("tel:")) { //Make the substring, and call the intent to dial, and in the else, use view.loadUrl(url);   } got it?

Comment: I was able to figure it out it had to do with the way i set up my functions after i fixed the functions everything worked fine. thanks for your help.

Comment: But it wasn't the right answer....lol It was a syntax error...How i placed my functions.